# how come viewmodel is not cleared when screen orientation change?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity, viewmodel, android-jetpack

So as we know these methods will be called when orientation change in `Activity`.

onPause() -> onSaveInstanceState() -> onStop() -> onDestroy() -> onCreate() -> onStart() -> onRestoreInstanceState() -> onResume()

So we can see the `onDestroy()` method is called.

If the `ViewModel()` is lifecycle aware then how come the viewmodel is not cleared and preserving the data?

Comment: See https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#lifecycle

Answer (score 2):

Being lifecycle-aware doesn't mean that ViewModel has the same lifecycle with Activities/Fragments. `onClear()` method is called when an Activity finishes (and a Fragment is detached).

There's a nice graph comparing Activitie's and ViewModel's lifecycle in this [documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#lifecycle)

Comment: Thanks :) It seems my question is duplicate I really appreciate your answer!